# On road checking using Osm map

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Hi i have turn by turn navigation app using osm map.
I can show the road path from source to destination but how can i check the current position(GPS) is within the road or away while traveling in a car.

this is the link i am using to get road path
OSRMRoadManager.getRoad:http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?&loc=19.112745999999998,73.00902099999999&loc=18.651449,73.344726&instructions=true&alt=false.

**Edit**:
I need to alert the user if he get diverted from the selected rout.

Comment: You can measure the distance of the point to the road and if it is larger than 50m away you are probably off the road. Or what is the question?

Comment: @ Karussell thax for reply.  50m is an approximate distance to check .Is there any way to get width of the selected road.

Comment: I fear not, you can just estimate from the highway tag (if you store this information somewhere)